# error in sql...invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by

Tags: sql

i have problem with my query!
when this instruction is execute , this error will be appear:

```
SELECT   counter, ArticleID, username
FROM     ArticleRev
GROUP BY username
```

invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by cluse error in sql

please help me... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is meaningless, and the error is telling you why. Let's elaborate a little.

You have written `GROUP BY username`, which means that from all the values of `counter` and `ArticleID` among rows with the same `username`, this query will return just one of each. But *which one*? You don't specify a way to select a value from among all possible choices, so the server is telling you that the query is invalid.

You should better explain what is your intent here; while we can explain why the query is invalid it's impossible to suggest a valid query without more information.

Answer (score 0):

since you are grouping the result by the `username`, the`counter` and `ArticleID` must be ***aggregated***. For instance:

```
SELECT   COUNT(counter), COUNT(ArticleID), username
FROM     ArticleRev
GROUP BY username
```

**COUNT( )** is an example of **[Aggregate Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function)**.

 **[See Here for GROUP BY Clause.](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7080.asp)**